# Share context data with all children of a control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I need all children of a view to know a piece of contextual information (the person they need to show).  I also need the approach to be compatible with MVVM.  I tried to do this with RegionContext in my Prism application.  Here's my approach and problems:

I have a TabControl that I use View Injection to populate with views so that I can populate RegionContext:

From Shell.xaml:

```
<TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Right" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="TabRegion">
```

And here's my injection

```
//Create an instance of ContactView.xaml
contactView = CreateContactView(contact);
_regionManager.Regions["TabRegion"].Add(contactView, contactKey, true);

//"contact" being a simple entity of type Contact
RegionManager.SetRegionContext(contactViewb, contact);
```

What I *expected* was to be able to use an attached property to get the value of the RegionContext from any control that is a child of that DependencyObject (ContactView.xaml) via the RegionManager.RegionContext attached property:

From ContactView.xaml

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding 
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
     Path=(cal:RegionManager.RegionContext)}"/>
```

But this doesn't work... I have to find ContactView.xaml to get it to work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding 
     RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
          Mode=FindAncestor, 
          AncestorType={x:Type views:ContactView}}, 
     Path=(cal:RegionManager.RegionContext)}"/>
```

This is fine, however I'm going to allow modules to load views into ContactView and I would prefer they didn't have to know anything about ContactView.

I guess my question really is, **how are you expected to load a complicated view with lots of controls and regions and have them all share one piece of context data?**

What is the right way to do this?  Scoped container?  Write a new attached property that runs up the control hierarchy to find the RegionContext (ugh)?  I'm not using RegionContext correctly?  I'm open to anything.  Suggest away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better design avoids using RegionContext altogether.  That is a sort of poor man's dependency injection in that it can host only one object.  Using a scoped Unity container into which you inject the contact would lead to better testability of the ViewModel and will avoid the inevitable conflict when needing two items in RegionContext.

Comment: Yeah... I see your point.  I am concerned that the container will become a dumping ground for data, however it's likely the best place for "ambient" data to live.

Comment: Also... what the heck is RegionContext good for?  The "Context" part of the name seems misleading.

Comment: Can you give link to example of 'scoped Unity container' in prism? I can not find it in google.